# how to group by nearby values using data.tables

Tags: r, data.table, time-series

My data looks like this:

```
    ID1     ID2     Time            diff
1:  1958616 P209576 4/15/2016 7:46  NA mins
2:  1958493 P209580 3/23/2016 9:41  -33005.16793 mins
3:  1958493 P209580 3/25/2016 15:41 3240.09742 mins
4:  1958493 P209580 3/30/2016 10:22 6880.65360 mins
5:  1958492 P209580 3/30/2016 11:31 69.00078 mins
6:  1958493 P209580 4/11/2016 10:07 17196.62313 mins
```

What I'd like to do is group all IDs that occur within an 8 hour time window of each other and also return the number of distinct ID1s after grouping. In the above example, rows 4 & 5 would be grouped since `abs(diff) < 60*8`.

I used `data[, diff := TIME - shift(TIME)]` to generate the diff column.

My ideal output would look something like this

```
    num_of_unique_id1   ID2     Initial_time
1:  1                   P209576 4/15/2016 7:46
2:  1                   P209580 3/23/2016 9:41
3:  1                   P209580 3/25/2016 15:41
4:  2                   P209580 3/30/2016 10:22
5:  1                   P209580 4/11/2016 10:07
```

I'm thinking that `num_of_unique_id1` could be created using `.SD` and `length(unique(ID1))` but not sure how to create column for `by =` parameter.

I know theres also going to be boundary issues that arise (A is within 8 hours of B and B is within 8 hours of C but A and C are more than 8 hours apart) and in these cases I think I would like to group it all into one row.

output of `dput(data)`

```
structure(list(ID1 = c("1958616", "1958493", "1958493", "1958493",
"1958492", "1958493"), ID2 = c("P209576", "P209580", "P209580",
"P209580", "P209580", "P209580"), Time = structure(c(1460706387.438,
1458726077.362, 1458920483.207, 1459333322.423, 1459337462.47,
1460369259.858), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"),
    diff = structure(c(NA, -33005.1679333329, 3240.09741666714,
    6880.65360000133, 69.0007833321889, 17196.6231333335), units = "mins", class = "difftime")), .Names = c("ID1",
"ID2", "Time", "diff"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,
-6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x1ce9a28>)
```

Comment: Can you use `dput` on the `head` of your data to provide reproducible data? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: "What I'd like to do is group all IDs that occur within an 8 hour time window of each other"... you want within 8-hour time window of the *previous* (in time) entry? Why don't you sort the data by time first?

Comment: Or, do the data need to stay in the order it comes?

Comment: I sorted by ID2 first then Time. Yes group by previous time entry assuming that ID2 is the same. Data does not need to stay in the order that it comes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the data are ordered in time, we can compute the diff and assign unique groups using `cumsum`.

```
data <- data[order(Time)]
data[ , diff := NULL]  # we will re-compute diff in hours
data[ , diff_hours := as.numeric(c(0, diff(Time)))]
##        ID1     ID2                Time diff_hours
## 1: 1958493 P209580 2016-03-23 09:41:17   0.000000
## 2: 1958493 P209580 2016-03-25 15:41:23  54.001624
## 3: 1958493 P209580 2016-03-30 10:22:02 114.677560
## 4: 1958492 P209580 2016-03-30 11:31:02   1.150013
## 5: 1958493 P209580 2016-04-11 10:07:39 286.610386
## 6: 1958616 P209576 2016-04-15 07:46:27  93.646550

window <- 8  # the time window in hours
data[ , group := cumsum(diff_hours > window) + 1]
data[ , num_of_unique_id1 := uniqueN(ID1), by = group]
##        ID1     ID2                Time diff_hours group num_of_unique_id1
## 1: 1958493 P209580 2016-03-23 09:41:17   0.000000     1                 1
## 2: 1958493 P209580 2016-03-25 15:41:23  54.001624     2                 1
## 3: 1958493 P209580 2016-03-30 10:22:02 114.677560     3                 2
## 4: 1958492 P209580 2016-03-30 11:31:02   1.150013     3                 2
## 5: 1958493 P209580 2016-04-11 10:07:39 286.610386     4                 1
## 6: 1958616 P209576 2016-04-15 07:46:27  93.646550     5                 1
```

Note that the two data points on `2016-03-30` within about an hour of each other are assigned the same `group` and the `num_of_unique_id1` (per group) is 2, whereas all the other data points are in their own group.